# Usage of "but then"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Does the usage of "but then" in this sentence correct?

> I love all my family, but then I love my mother more.

I read in the Collins Dictionary that we can use 'but then'  before a remark which suggests that what you have just said should not be regarded as surprising.

Does "but then" in my sentence means the same thing as I read in the Collins Dictionary?

Comment: You're not using it correctly, but then, you're not completely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of the use you described:

> He was hired as Assistant Vice President fresh out of university. But then, his father is the CEO.

Comment: Does the usage of "but then" in my sentence correct?

Comment: It's not incorrect, but it doesn't  use the phrase in the way that it is used to introduce a fact which explains why the preceding remark is not as surprising as it might seem on its face.

Comment: What does 'but then ' means in my sentence?

Comment: Your sentence is not quite idiomatic. If you mean to say that your mother is your favorite, that you love her more than you love the other members of your family, you would say "... but I love my mother *the most*".  I am not quite sure of your meaning with "but then". It seems as if you've left something out of your first clause, such as "I do love my family *very much*, but then, I love my mother the most".    *but then* is a kind of qualification of what has just been said, but you've not said anything that is subject to qualification.

Comment: thank you, what did you mean by qualification ?

Comment: A qualification (from the verb **to qualify** as in "to qualify a remark") is a word or phrase that  limits or modifies a preceding remark. For example, in the sentence "No pets are allowed on the airplane *unless they are emotional support animals*" the italicized clause is a "qualification" of the preceding remark forbidding animals on the flight.

Comment: I searched in many dictionaries but I didn't find that "but then" used to qualify a preceding remark, could you please give me a synonym of "but then" in the context to qualify a remark,Thank you

Comment: *The smoke alarm is beeping every few minutes, **but that is to be expected** since we have not changed the battery in over a year.*

Comment: "I do love my family very much, but then, I love my mother the most" but in this sentence we couldn't replace "but then" by "but that  is to be expected" ,is there a synonym fits with this sentence?

Comment: *I like all kinds of ice cream, but then, chocolate is my favorite.*   *but then* there is rather like "but if I had to pick a favorite" or "but truth be told". It is qualifying the word **all**.  So too your sentence. *I love all of my family dearly, but truth be told, I do love my mother the most.*

Comment: could we delete "dearly" and say simply "I love all of my family ,but then, I do love my mother the most."?

Comment: Though **dearly** does help to establish the assertion which you're qualifying, it is not absolutely necessary to the meaning, and it could be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Another example that is more common, and in line with the Collins Dictionary, is something like, "He won first place! But then again, it's no surprise because he was always studying on the weekends."